# R eval parse character limit

Tags: r

Does anyone know if there's a character limit to what can be put into `eval(parse())` ?

I have a very long character string I am putting into eval parse, and am getting a warning message that has part of the string cut out.

Comment: `library(fortunes); fortune(181)` ;-)

Comment: [Fortune 106](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fortunes/vignettes/fortunes.pdf): "If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question."

Comment: @Roland indeed `106` works too

Comment: `?parse` - "When input is taken from the console, n = NULL is equivalent to n = 1, and n < 0 will read until an EOF character is read. (The EOF character is Ctrl-Z for the Windows front-ends.) The line-length limit is 4095 bytes when reading from the console (which may impose a lower limit: see ‘An Introduction to R’)."

Comment: In what way is the question not clear or hard to understand ? A clear answer has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit for `parse()` is 4095 bytes when reading from the console.

Referring to the manual at https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/parse.html

> The line-length limit is 4095 bytes when reading from the console (which may impose a lower limit: see ‘An Introduction to R’).

Comment: If the input is not from the console and depending on your input, you might also run into a limit given by `?options`, see `expressions`.