# Problems saving matrix as object in R

Tags: r, object, matrix

Okay, so if I build this matrix,

```
matrix(c(checksheet$Salary, checksheet$PG, checksheet$PG, checksheet$SG, checksheet$SG, checksheet$SF, checksheet$SF, checksheet$PF, checksheet$PF, checksheet$C, checksheet$C, checksheet$G, checksheet$G, checksheet$FF, checksheet$FF, checksheet$UTIL, checksheet$CC, checksheet$oquinky01, checksheet$harremo01, checksheet$redicjj01, checksheet$simmobe01, checksheet$bogdabo02, checksheet$dedmode01, checksheet$makerth01, checksheet$turneev01, checksheet$hieldbu01, checksheet$ibakase01, checksheet$greenda02, checksheet$wiggian01, checksheet$hardati02, checksheet$butleji01, checksheet$batumni01, checksheet$horfoal01, checksheet$middlkh01, checksheet$sabondo01, checksheet$ilyaser01, checksheet$vonleno01, checksheet$favorde01, checksheet$iguodan01, checksheet$looneke01, checksheet$millspa01, checksheet$evansty01, checksheet$matthwe02, checksheet$allenja01, checksheet$harrijo01, checksheet$harrito02, checksheet$gallida01, checksheet$dinwisp01, checksheet$abrinal01, checksheet$georgpa01, checksheet$bookede01, checksheet$anderry01, checksheet$adamsst01, checksheet$holidju01, checksheet$townska01, checksheet$dienggo01, checksheet$gasolma01, checksheet$gibsota01, checksheet$jonesda03, checksheet$derozde01, checksheet$duranke01, checksheet$livinsh01, checksheet$foxde01, checksheet$pattepa01, checksheet$westbru01, checksheet$kanteen01, checksheet$lillada01, checksheet$leonaka01, checksheet$inglejo01, checksheet$vucevni01, checksheet$harriga01, checksheet$simmojo02, checksheet$bartowi01, checksheet$davisan02, checksheet$mcgruro01, checksheet$richajo01, checksheet$winslju01, checksheet$griffbl01, checksheet$caulewi01, checksheet$youngth01, checksheet$bazemke01, checksheet$mooreet01, checksheet$leeco01, checksheet$brownja02, checksheet$colliza01, checksheet$aldrila01, checksheet$doncilu01, checksheet$bembrde01, checksheet$davised01, checksheet$morrima02, checksheet$cartewe01, checksheet$jerebjo01, checksheet$klebima01, checksheet$randlju01, checksheet$plumlma01, checksheet$rosste01, checksheet$greenje02, checksheet$porteot01, checksheet$arizatr01, checksheet$bealbr01, checksheet$korkmfu01, checksheet$collijo01, checksheet$nancela02, checksheet$bogdabo01, checksheet$caldwke01, checksheet$olynyke01, checksheet$shumpim01, checksheet$kennalu01, checksheet$muscami01, checksheet$lambje01, checksheet$portibo01, checksheet$adebaba01, checksheet$baglema01, checksheet$ellenhe01, checksheet$farieke01, checksheet$ingrabr01, checksheet$templga01, checksheet$fournev01, checksheet$huertke01, checksheet$breweco01, checksheet$holmeri01, checksheet$anderky01, checksheet$leoname01, checksheet$greendr01, checksheet$siakapa01, checksheet$bridgmi01, checksheet$kornelu01, checksheet$dotsoda01, checksheet$gordoer01, checksheet$belinma01, checksheet$poweldw01, checksheet$waitedi01, checksheet$satorto01, checksheet$chrisma01, checksheet$bullore01, checksheet$milescj01, checksheet$powelno01, checksheet$leverca01, checksheet$shamela01, checksheet$oubreke01, checksheet$couside01, checksheet$ellinwa01, checksheet$mirotni01, checksheet$loveke01, checksheet$birchkh01, checksheet$greenge01, checksheet$crabbal01, checksheet$hoodro01, checksheet$nowitdi01, checksheet$markkla01, checksheet$seldewa01, checksheet$connapa01, checksheet$wilsodj01, checksheet$harrish01, checksheet$diallch01, checksheet$bryanth01, checksheet$stephla01, checksheet$korveky01, checksheet$alkinra01, checksheet$bacondw01, checksheet$jacksju01, checksheet$woodch01, checksheet$rabbiv01, checksheet$browntr01, checksheet$jonesje01, checksheet$wagnemo01, checksheet$motiedo01, checksheet$brownst02, checksheet$craigto01, checksheet$kaminfr01, checksheet$divindo01, checksheet$labissk01, checksheet$brownbr01, checksheet$clarkjo01, checksheet$washipj01, checksheet$mclembe01, checksheet$clarkbr01, checksheet$jamesle01, checksheet$cabocbr01, checksheet$hartjo01, checksheet$porzikr01, checksheet$walkelo01, checksheet$dunnkr01, checksheet$jacksja02, checksheet$brookdi01, checksheet$okogijo01, checksheet$robindu01, checksheet$tuckepj01, checksheet$grantje01, checksheet$leeda03), nrow = 190, byrow = TRUE)
```

It seems to work.

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19]
  [1,] 6900 3000 3000 3500 5700 5700 5600 5400 7100  7100  3100  3200  5300  4400  4400  3100  3000  3000  6100
  [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     1     1
  [3,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     1     1
  [4,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     1     1
  [5,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     1     1
  [6,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
  [7,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
       [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31] [,32] [,33] [,34] [,35] [,36]
  [1,]  3700  3700  3000  3700  4400  3000  5100  5100  3300  3000  3000  3000  3000  3000 10600 10600  3000
  [2,]     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
  [3,]     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
  [4,]     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     0
  [5,]     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     0
  [6,]     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
  [7,]     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
       [,37] [,38] [,39] [,40] [,41] [,42] [,43] [,44] [,45] [,46] [,47] [,48] [,49] [,50] [,51] [,52] [,53]
  [1,]  8200  3100  3100  3000  3000  3100  3000  3000  3500  3600  3600  3000  3200  3200  3200  3000  3000
  [2,]     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
  [3,]     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
  [4,]     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
  [5,]     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
  [6,]     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
  [7,]     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
       [,54] [,55] [,56] [,57] [,58] [,59] [,60] [,61] [,62] [,63] [,64] [,65] [,66] [,67] [,68] [,69] [,70]
  [1,]  4700  4700  4300  4300  6500  6500  4200  4900  4900  7700  3000  8400  8400  4800  4800  6200  6200
  [2,]     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
  [3,]     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
  [4,]     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
  [5,]     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
  [6,]     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
  [7,]     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
       [,71] [,72] [,73] [,74] [,75] [,76] [,77] [,78] [,79] [,80] [,81] [,82] [,83] [,84] [,85] [,86] [,87]
  [1,]  4000  4000  4000  4500  3000  3000 10300 10300  8900  3900  5200  3900  3100  3100  3100  3000  3500
  [2,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
  [3,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
  [4,]     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
  [5,]     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
  [6,]     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1
  [7,]     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1
       [,88] [,89] [,90] [,91] [,92] [,93] [,94] [,95] [,96] [,97] [,98] [,99] [,100] [,101] [,102] [,103]
  [1,]  3500  4700  3000  3000  3000  3000  4100  4100  6700  3500  3000  3000   3000   3000   3200   3200
  [2,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1      0      0      0      0
  [3,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1      0      0      0      0
  [4,]     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1      0      1      0      0
  [5,]     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1      0      1      0      0
  [6,]     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0      1      0      0      0
  [7,]     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0      1      0      0      0
       [,104] [,105] [,106] [,107] [,108] [,109] [,110] [,111] [,112] [,113] [,114] [,115] [,116] [,117] [,118]
  [1,]   6000   3000   4400   3000   3100   3700   3700   3000   3000   3300   3500   3500   5800   7500   7500
  [2,]      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  [3,]      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  [4,]      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
  [5,]      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
  [6,]      1      1      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      1      0      0
  [7,]      1      1      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      1      0      0
       [,119] [,120] [,121] [,122] [,123] [,124] [,125] [,126] [,127] [,128] [,129] [,130] [,131] [,132] [,133]
  [1,]   3800   4600   4600   4500   4500   5900   4600   7900   3600   9300   9300   3200   3800   3800   3000
  [2,]      1      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      0      0      1      1      0      0      0
  [3,]      1      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      0      0      1      1      0      0      0
  [4,]      1      0      1      0      1      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  [5,]      1      0      1      0      1      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  [6,]      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0      1      1      0      0      0      0      0
  [7,]      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0      1      1      0      0      0      0      0
       [,134] [,135] [,136] [,137] [,138] [,139] [,140] [,141] [,142]
  [1,]   3000   5000   5000   3600   3600   3000   3000   3000   9600
  [2,]      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      1
  [3,]      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      1
  [4,]      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0
  [5,]      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0      0
  [6,]      0      1      0      1      0      1      0      1      0
  [7,]      0      1      0      1      0      1      0      1      0
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 183 rows ]
```

However, when I try to save the exact same matrix as an object, I get the '+' sign indicating that R wants more.

```
> f.conreal <- matrix(c(checksheet$Salary, checksheet$PG, checksheet$PG, checksheet$SG, checksheet$SG, checksheet$SF, checksheet$SF, checksheet$PF, checksheet$PF, checksheet$C, checksheet$C, checksheet$G, checksheet$G, checksheet$FF, checksheet$FF, checksheet$UTIL, checksheet$CC, checksheet$oquinky01, checksheet$harremo01, checksheet$redicjj01, checksheet$simmobe01, checksheet$bogdabo02, checksheet$dedmode01, checksheet$makerth01, checksheet$turneev01, checksheet$hieldbu01, checksheet$ibakase01, checksheet$greenda02, checksheet$wiggian01, checksheet$hardati02, checksheet$butleji01, checksheet$batumni01, checksheet$horfoal01, checksheet$middlkh01, checksheet$sabondo01, checksheet$ilyaser01, checksheet$vonleno01, checksheet$favorde01, checksheet$iguodan01, checksheet$looneke01, checksheet$millspa01, checksheet$evansty01, checksheet$matthwe02, checksheet$allenja01, checksheet$harrijo01, checksheet$harrito02, checksheet$gallida01, checksheet$dinwisp01, checksheet$abrinal01, checksheet$georgpa01, checksheet$bookede01, checksheet$anderry01, checksheet$adamsst01, checksheet$holidju01, checksheet$townska01, checksheet$dienggo01, checksheet$gasolma01, checksheet$gibsota01, checksheet$jonesda03, checksheet$derozde01, checksheet$duranke01, checksheet$livinsh01, checksheet$foxde01, checksheet$pattepa01, checksheet$westbru01, checksheet$kanteen01, checksheet$lillada01, checksheet$leonaka01, checksheet$inglejo01, checksheet$vucevni01, checksheet$harriga01, checksheet$simmojo02, checksheet$bartowi01, checksheet$davisan02, checksheet$mcgruro01, checksheet$richajo01, checksheet$winslju01, checksheet$griffbl01, checksheet$caulewi01, checksheet$youngth01, checksheet$bazemke01, checksheet$mooreet01, checksheet$leeco01, checksheet$brownja02, checksheet$colliza01, checksheet$aldrila01, checksheet$doncilu01, checksheet$bembrde01, checksheet$davised01, checksheet$morrima02, checksheet$cartewe01, checksheet$jerebjo01, checksheet$klebima01, checksheet$randlju01, checksheet$plumlma01, checksheet$rosste01, checksheet$greenje02, checksheet$porteot01, checksheet$arizatr01, checksheet$bealbr01, checksheet$korkmfu01, checksheet$collijo01, checksheet$nancela02, checksheet$bogdabo01, checksheet$caldwke01, checksheet$olynyke01, checksheet$shumpim01, checksheet$kennalu01, checksheet$muscami01, checksheet$lambje01, checksheet$portibo01, checksheet$adebaba01, checksheet$baglema01, checksheet$ellenhe01, checksheet$farieke01, checksheet$ingrabr01, checksheet$templga01, checksheet$fournev01, checksheet$huertke01, checksheet$breweco01, checksheet$holmeri01, checksheet$anderky01, checksheet$leoname01, checksheet$greendr01, checksheet$siakapa01, checksheet$bridgmi01, checksheet$kornelu01, checksheet$dotsoda01, checksheet$gordoer01, checksheet$belinma01, checksheet$poweldw01, checksheet$waitedi01, checksheet$satorto01, checksheet$chrisma01, checksheet$bullore01, checksheet$milescj01, checksheet$powelno01, checksheet$leverca01, checksheet$shamela01, checksheet$oubreke01, checksheet$couside01, checksheet$ellinwa01, checksheet$mirotni01, checksheet$loveke01, checksheet$birchkh01, checksheet$greenge01, checksheet$crabbal01, checksheet$hoodro01, checksheet$nowitdi01, checksheet$markkla01, checksheet$seldewa01, checksheet$connapa01, checksheet$wilsodj01, checksheet$harrish01, checksheet$diallch01, checksheet$bryanth01, checksheet$stephla01, checksheet$korveky01, checksheet$alkinra01, checksheet$bacondw01, checksheet$jacksju01, checksheet$woodch01, checksheet$rabbiv01, checksheet$browntr01, checksheet$jonesje01, checksheet$wagnemo01, checksheet$motiedo01, checksheet$brownst02, checksheet$craigto01, checksheet$kaminfr01, checksheet$divindo01, checksheet$labissk01, checksheet$brownbr01, checksheet$clarkjo01, checksheet$washipj01, checksheet$mclembe01, checksheet$clarkbr01, checksheet$jamesle01, checksheet$cabocbr01, checksheet$hartjo01, checksheet$porzikr01, checksheet$walkelo01, checksheet$dunnkr01, checksheet$jacksja02, checksheet$brookdi01, checksheet$okogijo01, checksheet$robindu01, checksheet$tuckepj01, checksheet$grantje01, checksheet$leeda03), nrow = 190, byrow = TRUE)
+
```

Now, if I simply change what I'm calling that object, it seems to work again.

```
> wtf <- matrix(c(checksheet$Salary, checksheet$PG, checksheet$PG, checksheet$SG, checksheet$SG, checksheet$SF, checksheet$SF, checksheet$PF, checksheet$PF, checksheet$C, checksheet$C, checksheet$G, checksheet$G, checksheet$FF, checksheet$FF, checksheet$UTIL, checksheet$CC, checksheet$oquinky01, checksheet$harremo01, checksheet$redicjj01, checksheet$simmobe01, checksheet$bogdabo02, checksheet$dedmode01, checksheet$makerth01, checksheet$turneev01, checksheet$hieldbu01, checksheet$ibakase01, checksheet$greenda02, checksheet$wiggian01, checksheet$hardati02, checksheet$butleji01, checksheet$batumni01, checksheet$horfoal01, checksheet$middlkh01, checksheet$sabondo01, checksheet$ilyaser01, checksheet$vonleno01, checksheet$favorde01, checksheet$iguodan01, checksheet$looneke01, checksheet$millspa01, checksheet$evansty01, checksheet$matthwe02, checksheet$allenja01, checksheet$harrijo01, checksheet$harrito02, checksheet$gallida01, checksheet$dinwisp01, checksheet$abrinal01, checksheet$georgpa01, checksheet$bookede01, checksheet$anderry01, checksheet$adamsst01, checksheet$holidju01, checksheet$townska01, checksheet$dienggo01, checksheet$gasolma01, checksheet$gibsota01, checksheet$jonesda03, checksheet$derozde01, checksheet$duranke01, checksheet$livinsh01, checksheet$foxde01, checksheet$pattepa01, checksheet$westbru01, checksheet$kanteen01, checksheet$lillada01, checksheet$leonaka01, checksheet$inglejo01, checksheet$vucevni01, checksheet$harriga01, checksheet$simmojo02, checksheet$bartowi01, checksheet$davisan02, checksheet$mcgruro01, checksheet$richajo01, checksheet$winslju01, checksheet$griffbl01, checksheet$caulewi01, checksheet$youngth01, checksheet$bazemke01, checksheet$mooreet01, checksheet$leeco01, checksheet$brownja02, checksheet$colliza01, checksheet$aldrila01, checksheet$doncilu01, checksheet$bembrde01, checksheet$davised01, checksheet$morrima02, checksheet$cartewe01, checksheet$jerebjo01, checksheet$klebima01, checksheet$randlju01, checksheet$plumlma01, checksheet$rosste01, checksheet$greenje02, checksheet$porteot01, checksheet$arizatr01, checksheet$bealbr01, checksheet$korkmfu01, checksheet$collijo01, checksheet$nancela02, checksheet$bogdabo01, checksheet$caldwke01, checksheet$olynyke01, checksheet$shumpim01, checksheet$kennalu01, checksheet$muscami01, checksheet$lambje01, checksheet$portibo01, checksheet$adebaba01, checksheet$baglema01, checksheet$ellenhe01, checksheet$farieke01, checksheet$ingrabr01, checksheet$templga01, checksheet$fournev01, checksheet$huertke01, checksheet$breweco01, checksheet$holmeri01, checksheet$anderky01, checksheet$leoname01, checksheet$greendr01, checksheet$siakapa01, checksheet$bridgmi01, checksheet$kornelu01, checksheet$dotsoda01, checksheet$gordoer01, checksheet$belinma01, checksheet$poweldw01, checksheet$waitedi01, checksheet$satorto01, checksheet$chrisma01, checksheet$bullore01, checksheet$milescj01, checksheet$powelno01, checksheet$leverca01, checksheet$shamela01, checksheet$oubreke01, checksheet$couside01, checksheet$ellinwa01, checksheet$mirotni01, checksheet$loveke01, checksheet$birchkh01, checksheet$greenge01, checksheet$crabbal01, checksheet$hoodro01, checksheet$nowitdi01, checksheet$markkla01, checksheet$seldewa01, checksheet$connapa01, checksheet$wilsodj01, checksheet$harrish01, checksheet$diallch01, checksheet$bryanth01, checksheet$stephla01, checksheet$korveky01, checksheet$alkinra01, checksheet$bacondw01, checksheet$jacksju01, checksheet$woodch01, checksheet$rabbiv01, checksheet$browntr01, checksheet$jonesje01, checksheet$wagnemo01, checksheet$motiedo01, checksheet$brownst02, checksheet$craigto01, checksheet$kaminfr01, checksheet$divindo01, checksheet$labissk01, checksheet$brownbr01, checksheet$clarkjo01, checksheet$washipj01, checksheet$mclembe01, checksheet$clarkbr01, checksheet$jamesle01, checksheet$cabocbr01, checksheet$hartjo01, checksheet$porzikr01, checksheet$walkelo01, checksheet$dunnkr01, checksheet$jacksja02, checksheet$brookdi01, checksheet$okogijo01, checksheet$robindu01, checksheet$tuckepj01, checksheet$grantje01, checksheet$leeda03), nrow = 190, byrow = TRUE)
```

All of this was working fine yesterday with the original object name. What on Earth is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single line of code that you type in the console can only be up to 4095 bytes long as documented on the `?parse` help page and previously answered on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36404576/r-eval-parse-character-limit). With the longer variable name, you just go over the max line length (4096).

You can add a newline into that very long string so as to not exceed the max single line length

Or instead of repeating `checksheet$` so many times, you can use a `with()` statement.

```
f.conreal <- with(checksheet, matrix(c(Salary, PG, PG, SG, SG, SF, SF, PF, PF, C, C, G, G, FF, FF, UTIL, CC, oquinky01, harremo01, redicjj01, simmobe01, bogdabo02, dedmode01, makerth01, turneev01, hieldbu01, ibakase01, greenda02, wiggian01, hardati02, butleji01, batumni01, horfoal01, middlkh01, sabondo01, ilyaser01, vonleno01, favorde01, iguodan01, looneke01, millspa01, evansty01, matthwe02, allenja01, harrijo01, harrito02, gallida01, dinwisp01, abrinal01, georgpa01, bookede01, anderry01, adamsst01, holidju01, townska01, dienggo01, gasolma01, gibsota01, jonesda03, derozde01, duranke01, livinsh01, foxde01, pattepa01, westbru01, kanteen01, lillada01, leonaka01, inglejo01, vucevni01, harriga01, simmojo02, bartowi01, davisan02, mcgruro01, richajo01, winslju01, griffbl01, caulewi01, youngth01, bazemke01, mooreet01, leeco01, brownja02, colliza01, aldrila01, doncilu01, bembrde01, davised01, morrima02, cartewe01, jerebjo01, klebima01, randlju01, plumlma01, rosste01, greenje02, porteot01, arizatr01, bealbr01, korkmfu01, collijo01, nancela02, bogdabo01, caldwke01, olynyke01, shumpim01, kennalu01, muscami01, lambje01, portibo01, adebaba01, baglema01, ellenhe01, farieke01, ingrabr01, templga01, fournev01, huertke01, breweco01, holmeri01, anderky01, leoname01, greendr01, siakapa01, bridgmi01, kornelu01, dotsoda01, gordoer01, belinma01, poweldw01, waitedi01, satorto01, chrisma01, bullore01, milescj01, powelno01, leverca01, shamela01, oubreke01, couside01, ellinwa01, mirotni01, loveke01, birchkh01, greenge01, crabbal01, hoodro01, nowitdi01, markkla01, seldewa01, connapa01, wilsodj01, harrish01, diallch01, bryanth01, stephla01, korveky01, alkinra01, bacondw01, jacksju01, woodch01, rabbiv01, browntr01, jonesje01, wagnemo01, motiedo01, brownst02, craigto01, kaminfr01, divindo01, labissk01, brownbr01, clarkjo01, washipj01, mclembe01, clarkbr01, jamesle01, cabocbr01, hartjo01, porzikr01, walkelo01, dunnkr01, jacksja02, brookdi01, okogijo01, robindu01, tuckepj01, grantje01, leeda03), nrow = 190, byrow = TRUE))
```