# Cannot import a simple vector in R : why?

Tags: r, vector, import

I would like to import in R this vector that contains the names of several variables :

```
names14 <- c("INAMI","HcwProfession","code_qualif","espaces","start_convention","end_convention","date_adh_convention","date_refus_convention","n_limitations","jour_a1","h_s_a1","m_s_a1","h_e_a1","m_e_a1","jour_b1","h_s_b1","m_s_b1","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na1","type1","INAMI1","lieu1","postal1","ins1","local1","province1","com1","start1","end1","jour_a2","h_s_a2","m_s_a2","h_e_a2","m_e_a2","jour_b2","h_s_b2","m_s_b2","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na2","type2","INAMI2","lieu2","postal2","ins2","local2","province2","com2","start2","end2","jour_a3","h_s_a3","m_s_a3","h_e_a3","m_e_a3","jour_b3","h_s_b3","m_s_b3","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na3","type3","INAMI3","lieu3","postal3","ins3","local3","province3","com3","start3","end3","jour_a4","h_s_a4","m_s_a4","h_e_a4","m_e_a4","jour_b4","h_s_b4","m_s_b4","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na4","type4","INAMI4","lieu4","postal4","ins4","local4","province4","com4","start4","end4","jour_a5","h_s_a5","m_s_a5","h_e_a5","m_e_a5","jour_b5","h_s_b5","m_s_b5","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na5","type5","INAMI5","lieu5","postal5","ins5","local5","province5","com5","start5","end5","jour_a6","h_s_a6","m_s_a6","h_e_a6","m_e_a6","jour_b6","h_s_b6","m_s_b6","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na6","type6","INAMI6","lieu6","postal6","ins6","local6","province6","com6","start6","end6","jour_a7","h_s_a7","m_s_a7","h_e_a7","m_e_a7","jour_b7","h_s_b7","m_s_b7","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na7","type7","INAMI7","lieu7","postal7","ins7","local7","province7","com7","start7","end7","jour_a8","h_s_a8","m_s_a8","h_e_a8","m_e_a8","jour_b8","h_s_b8","m_s_b8","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na8","type8","INAMI8","lieu8","postal8","ins8","local8","province8","com8","start8","end8","jour_a9","h_s_a9","m_s_a9","h_e_a9","m_e_a9","jour_b9","h_s_b9","m_s_b9","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na9","type9","INAMI9","lieu9","postal9","ins9","local9","province9","com9","start9","end9","jour_a10","h_s_a10","m_s_a10","h_e_a10","m_e_a10","jour_b10","h_s_b10","m_s_b10","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na10","type10","INAMI10","lieu10","postal10","ins10","local10","province10","com10","start10","end10","jour_a11","h_s_a11","m_s_a11","h_e_a11","m_e_a11","jour_b11","h_s_b11","m_s_b11","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na11","type11","INAMI11","lieu11","postal11","ins11","local11","province11","com11","start11","end11","jour_a12","h_s_a12","m_s_a12","h_e_a12","m_e_a12","jour_b12","h_s_b12","m_s_b12","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na12","type12","INAMI12","lieu12","postal12","ins12","local12","province12","com12","start12","end12","jour_a13","h_s_a13","m_s_a13","h_e_a13","m_e_a13","jour_b13","h_s_b13","m_s_b13","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na13","type13","INAMI13","lieu13","postal13","ins13","local13","province13","com13","start13","end13","jour_a14","h_s_a14","m_s_a14","h_e_a14","m_e_a14","jour_b14","h_s_b14","m_s_b14","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na14","type14","INAMI14","lieu14","postal14","ins14","local14","province14","com14","start14","end14","jour_a15","h_s_a15","m_s_a15","h_e_a15","m_e_a15","jour_b15","h_s_b15","m_s_b15","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na15","type15","INAMI15","lieu15","postal15","ins15","local15","province15","com15","start15","end15","jour_a16","h_s_a16","m_s_a16","h_e_a16","m_e_a16","jour_b16","h_s_b16","m_s_b16","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na16","type16","INAMI16","lieu16","postal16","ins16","local16","province16","com16","start16","end16","jour_a17","h_s_a17","m_s_a17","h_e_a17","m_e_a17","jour_b17","h_s_b17","m_s_b17","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na17","type17","INAMI17","lieu17","postal17","ins17","local17","province17","com17","start17","end17","jour_a18","h_s_a18","m_s_a18","h_e_a18","m_e_a18","jour_b18","h_s_b18","m_s_b18","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na18","type18","INAMI18","lieu18","postal18","ins18","local18","province18","com18","start18","end18","jour_a19","h_s_a19","m_s_a19","h_e_a19","m_e_a19","jour_b19","h_s_b19","m_s_b19","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na19","type19","INAMI19","lieu19","postal19","ins19","local19","province19","com19","start19","end19","jour_a20","h_s_a20","m_s_a20","h_e_a20","m_e_a20","jour_b20","h_s_b20","m_s_b20","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na20","type20","INAMI20","lieu20","postal20","ins20","local20","province20","com20","start20","end20","jour_a21","h_s_a21","m_s_a21","h_e_a21","m_e_a21","jour_b21","h_s_b21","m_s_b21","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na21","type21","INAMI21","lieu21","postal21","ins21","local21","province21","com21","start21","end21","jour_a22","h_s_a22","m_s_a22","h_e_a22","m_e_a22","jour_b22","h_s_b22","m_s_b22","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na22","type22","INAMI22","lieu22","postal22","ins22","local22","province22","com22","start22","end22","jour_a23","h_s_a23","m_s_a23","h_e_a23","m_e_a23","jour_b23","h_s_b23","m_s_b23","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na23","type23","INAMI23","lieu23","postal23","ins23","local23","province23","com23","start23","end23","jour_a24","h_s_a24","m_s_a24","h_e_a24","m_e_a24","jour_b24","h_s_b24","m_s_b24","h_e_b1","h_e_b1","na24","type24","INAMI24","lieu24","postal24","ins24","local24","province24","com24","start24","end24")
```

But R tells me something is missing (it shows "+", telling me to add something), but I don't understand what ? It works if I shorten the vector, maybe it's too long ?

Comment: The problem is that very long lines of code may not be interpreted correctly when entered into the console. Instead, add some line breaks before you paste or write it to a file and `source` it instead.

Comment: The length limit in bytes when typing things at the console is 4095 bytes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36404576/r-eval-parse-character-limit. Your current string seems to be about 4860 bytes long.